# Safest way to create joinable threads in a python extension

Tags: python, c++, pthreads, boost-python, pthread-join

I'm working on a python extension which spawns threads with `pthread`. In this minimal example the spawned threads don't join back the main thread in python. On the contrary I have no trouble with running the library when linked with a C++ executable. What is a safe way to `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`for python extensions?

My `python_extension.cpp` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>


class myTestClass{

 public:
  myTestClass(){};
  void *print_message_function(void *ptr);
  void wrapperf();

}

void *myTestClass::print_message_function( void *ptr ){
  char *message;
  message = (char *) ptr;
  printf("%s \n", message);
}


void myTestClass::wrapperf()
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;
  char *message1 = "Thread 1";
  char *message2 = "Thread 2";
  int  iret1, iret2;

  /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

  iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
  iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

  /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
  /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
  /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

  pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

  printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
  printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);

}


// C Wrappers for the above C++ classes                                                                                                                                
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  myTestClass *newcase(){ return new myTestClass};
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


// Boost python                                                                                                                                                        
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib_py)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<myTestClass, boost::noncopyable>("myTestClass", init<std::string>())
    .def("wrapperf", &myTestClass::wrapperf)


  def("newcase", &newcase, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());
}
```

My python script is as follows:

```
import mylib_py 
obj = newcase()
obj.wrapperf()
x = 2 # Dummy line
```

Sometimes the output to this is:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 1 returns: 0
Thread 2 returns: 0
```

Sometimes it is just:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
```

And the threads don't join at all! How could I resolve this? Could this be because my python script has already proceeded to the next line `x=2` before `obj.wrapperf()` completes?

Comment: Your example code joins its threads before control is returned to Python. So what is your question? Are you trying to create long running threads that will overlap with Python?

Comment: Why use C headers instead of C++ headers? And why use `pthread` (unless you use a pre C++11 compiler)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo True, I built this minimal example from a [c example](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html). `pthreads` because its minimal and all that I need as my threads are asynchronous.

Comment: I see. Even so, I'd jump at `<thread>` and its friends asap though. It should make your code even more minimal :-) and safer (RAII mutex locks etc).

Comment: do u have something between pthread_create() and pthread_join() that may throw an exception??

Comment: @Gupta No. It works fine sometimes and sometimes not! Nothing in-between generates an execution. This am confident of.

Comment: or maybe the threads throw exceptions and the main thread cannot join them.

Comment: If the threads are throwing an exception would it be after creation or during? How do I systematically check when its throwing an exception if it is?

Comment: After creation.  Put the whole thread body (i.e. in your case print_messsage_function() body) inside a try block and see if any exceptions are thrown or not.

Comment: I confirm that no exceptions thrown

Comment: Does "the threads don't join at all" mean control does not return to Python, or are you judging that based on observed output?  Or some other way?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't return to python and I'm judging that based on the observed output